# If no matching row for a searched value found

Tags: excel, vba

I have some problems defining that check. It's only a part of whole code with `Do Until`loop.

If **any row in my sheet** matches searched value define `FindRow` as "1".

If matching **row is found** then `FindRow =` that row number.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TKSLIST").Range("A:A")
    FindRow = 1
    strTKSname = ws.Cells(i + 1, 11).Text
    
    If .Find(What:=strTKSname, LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False).Row Is Nothing Then
    FindRow = 1
    Else
    FindRow = .Find(What:=strTKSname, LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False).Row
    End If
End With
```

I'm missing there something. Everytime when my searched value is not found I'm getting errors.

Comment: You'll have to remove the first occurring `.Row`: `Nothing` is used for objects, not for integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Declare your variables properly
2. Get the range wher something was found as `FoundAt` and compare that against `Nothing`
3. Remove else part because `FindRow = 1` was already set as initial value.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TKSLIST").Range("A:A")
    Dim FindRow As Long
    FindRow = 1  ' this needs to be inside the loop (and you can omit the else part below)

    Dim strTKSname As String
    strTKSname = ws.Cells(i + 1, 11).Text
    
    Dim FoundAt As Range
    Set FoundAt = .Find(What:=strTKSname, LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then
        FindRow = FoundAt.Row
    End If 'no else needed because initialized as `FindRow = 1`
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using the Find Method in a Loop

```vb
Sub Whatever()

    ' somewhere before the loop
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim FindRow As Long

                    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TKSLIST").Range("A:A")
                        strTKSname = ws.Cells(i + 1, 11).Value
                        ' Just a reminder:
                        ' Without the 'After' the search starts with `A2`.
                        ' If that is ok with you, you don't need it.
                        Set fCell = .Find(What:=strTKSname, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                        If fCell Is Nothing Then
                            FindRow = 1
                        Else
                            FindRow = fCell.Row
                        End If
                    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually you don't need `Set fCell = Nothing` because `Find` always sets it to `Nothing` if nothing was found. You only need to `Set Nothing` if you use a method that throws an exception (because then it does not set to `Nothing`).

Comment: Thanks. But the `Else` statement is harboring the part when something was found (`Not fCell Is Nothing`). So for the next run, you surely want the variable set to `Nothing`. You should apply it to the `If` statement in your answer. Think about it. This oversight might have happened due to the fact that some developers exclusively use the 'positive' outcome to be the first statement. I don't.

Comment: No, if the first loop found something, then `Set fCell = .Find` will set `fCell` to nothing if it doesn't find anything in the second loop. Therefore `Set fCell = Nothing` it is not needed. Test it.

Comment: I'm on it. If what I think you're telling me is true, that's huge.

Comment: But careful that only works because `Find` **always** returns something (even if it is a `Nothing` it returns). This won't work with procedures that run into an exception instead (like `WorksheetFunction.Match` which throws an error instead of returning `Nothing`, so here you have to `Set` your variable `Nothing`).

Comment: And... you're right. It totally makes sense. How the heck could I have missed such a thing? Thanks again.

Comment: No worries ;) `Set fCell = Nothing` won't hurt, it is just not necessary here.